# Emulator for Azure service bus topics in local

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm new to Azure world. We are building a system which at a high level performs below 
1. Subscribes to a service bus topic (using Microsoft.azure.servicebus)
2. Listens to events (using Microsoft.azure.servicebus)
3. performs some action when event came into subscription

Curious to know if there is a way to locally emulates the Azure service bus topic without connecting to actual service bus. Our Idea is to use this emulator for development and testing in locally without connecting to azure service bus (for various reasons).

Found "Azure storage emulator", with which we can create queues and blob containers in local. I couldn't find option to create topics with "Azure storage emulator".

Guidance on how to emulate service bus topics in local and experiences on how test systems build around azure event bus topic would be of great help.

Found a similar question(asked in 2016) there were no emulators or approaches (except using actual azure service bus) are suggested. Hence asking again.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there's no way to emulate Azure Service Bus on-premises. And not likely you'll have a traditional emulator similar to what you'd like to have anytime soon.

Azure Storage emulator is intended for Storage Queues, which is another service and not Service Bus. Storage Queues is a queuing service that does not support pub/sub out of the box. In case the ability to test offline is a show stopper and you don't want to waste your time of building this capability, you could look into one of the messaging frameworks that operate on top of Azure Storage Queues service and provide pub/sub. One of those is [NServiceBus](https://docs.particular.net/get-started/) which has a [Storage Queue transport](https://docs.particular.net/transports/azure-storage-queues/).

Disclaimer: I work on NServiceBus.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a layer of abstraction (such as [MassTransit](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit)), you could swap out Azure Service bus for another message bus provider for something that is possible to run locally, such as [RabbitMQ](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server).  You could use configuration to set the appropriate service based on your environment.